# Android DrawerLayout listen for user dragging?

Tags: android, drawerlayout, onscrolllistener

I am looking for a way to listen for the user opening the DrawerLayout by dragging his finger, so I can read its current x and y values.
Something more 'in-depth' than simple open and close events from a DrawerListener.

My idea would be to implement a separate onTouchListener on the whole Activity and calculate drawer openings from intercepted touch events there but I would like to use a simpler approach if it exists.

Something like an onScrollListener or an onTouchListener where I can get the Drawer's current x and y or translationX and translationY values?

Comment: The `DrawerListener` interface provides an `onDrawerSlide()` method that has an offset parameter, indicating the fraction of its width a Drawer is open. It doesn't provide any way to determine a y-coordinate, though, if that is indeed necessary.

Comment: An offset will work! Would you mind posting this again as a reply, so I can accept it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DrawerListener` interface provides an `onDrawerSlide()` method that has an offset parameter, indicating the fraction of its width a Drawer is open.

```
public static abstract interface DrawerListener
{
    public abstract void onDrawerSlide(android.view.View drawerView, float slideOffset);
    ...
}
```